# How to extract and return one objectqitem from a json array file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json

my json is:

```
export  const wordTrans_ar =  [
        {
            "english_word": "window",
            "hebrew": "חלון",
        },

        {
            "english_word": "good",
            "hebrew": "טוב",
        }
[
```

i want my function (in react) to return only the 1st item (the english_word) of the 1st sell in my json array.

i traied : a_arr.english_word[0]

but it didn't work. why?

how do i write it?

Comment: You need to do a_arr[0].english_word instead. A_arr[0] accesses the first object in array then you can extract English_word from that object.

Answer (score 1):

you have to access the index of your array first, before you want to get the english_word property.
In your example, that would be:

wordTrans_ar[0].english_word

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```js
a_arr[0].english_word
```

You have to trace the object structure when accessing items.